# Gitflow, artifact versions and pull requests

Tags: git, branch, release-management, git-flow, semantic-versioning

We are using a variation of gitflow as our branching strategy. A project is initialized with the `master` branch with the artifact version (in pom.xml, we're using maven) set to `0.0.0` and a `dev` branch is where the version is updated to the snapshot version `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`:

[image: project initialization]

All this is done by an initialization script. Both these branches are [protected](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-protected-branches). Both the branches are also monitored by TeamCity jobs which trigger an artifact build at any commit.

All work is done using feature branches:

[image: Feature branch creation and merge]

The merge at the end is really a [pull request](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-pull-requests), which once approved, is merged and the feature branch deleted. This also triggers the build of the snapshot artifact (as there is a commit to `dev`).

Releasing is done by creating a release branch (a TeamCity job to "Start Release" which creates the branch and corrects the versions):

[image: Start release process]

Finalizing the release is where I'm having trouble:

[image: Finalize release]

We create a pull request from the release branch to `master` and `dev`. The pull request to `dev` has conflicts as the version was updated in both the branches separately. How should I resolve this?

- If I resolve the conflict to correct the version to `1.2.2-SNAPSHOT`
  in above, this creates a commit to the release branch, and messes
  with the pull request to `master`.
- If I resolve the conflict to not correct the version (as in the
  image) the commit to dev with version `1.1.2` (no snapshot) triggers
  an incorrect artifact build and deployment.

I'm also not sure what the version in `dev` should be after the merge. If the version in `dev` is `1.2.5-SNAPSHOT`, for example, and the release branch has the version `1.1.2`, what should to be the version after the release branch is merged to `dev`?

**Edit:**

A pull request with conflicts can only be resolved by making changes to the source branch:

[image: conflicts]

In the above example, `master` has the latest release, which i'm trying to pull into `dev`, which is causing a conflict in the pull-request. trying to resolve that is only possible by committing changes to `master`, which is wrong.

Comment: "If I resolve the conflict to correct the version to 1.2.2-SNAPSHOT in above, this creates a commit to the release branch, and messes with the pull request to master." Why? If you're resolving the conflict as part of a `merge` operation, the commit is only part of `dev`. Regardless, if you just do the merge to master before the `merge` to `dev`, this is a non-issue

Comment: @Vlad274 there is no 'merge' yet. It is still a pull request with conflicts. In a test repository I created a similar scenario. After the release is merged to `master`, I'm trying to merge `master` to `dev` (https://github.com/c0d3rb4b4/pullrequesttest/pull/2). This has conflicts, and the only way to resolve the conflicts is to make commits to `master`.

Comment: @Vlad274 Added a screenshot in the question above.

Comment: Oh. I see. You're doing PR `release` -> `master` then PR `master` -> `dev`. I typically do PR `release` -> `master` then PR `release` -> `dev`. Then, when resolving conflicts (via merging `dev` -> `release`), the commit gets added to `release` just before merging to `dev`. This process has worked for me since the `release` branch is about to be deleted.